# How to debug PHP script not executing?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, redirect

I'm working on a wordpress page here http://beta.fray.it/invite and on clicking the Twitter icon I have this onclick attribute set on a list element

```
onclick="window.location.href = '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/components/invite/twitter/redirect.php';">
```

this takes me to the php file which should redirect users to Twitter for authentication. I got this working on another server I use for testing, but not here. What happens is that I see content from the main page http://beta.fray.it but no redirection. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Are there any errors output to the page, or to an error log on the server?

Comment: What is inside redirect.php? becuase it show me a page. Maybe you didn't upload that file to the server.

Comment: I see no error output on the page. Checked the folder where I placed the files on the server and saw no error logs, where else could I check for these logs?

Comment: contents of redirect.php: <?php

session_start();
require_once('twitteroauth.php');
require_once('config.php');

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
$request_token = $connection->getRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK);

$oauth_token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $oauth_token;

$oauth_token_secret = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $oauth_token_secret;

$url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($oauth_token);
header('Location: '. $url);
?>

Comment: I uploaded 2 random files on the location above and tried to access them through the browser. This one http://beta.fray.it/wp-content/themes/fray/components/invite/twitter/github_ssh.txt outputs the contents of the text file correctly. However, this one does not http://beta.fray.it/wp-content/themes/fray/components/invite/twitter/mypage.php, seems like I cannot get any php files to execute

Comment: even if I request a non-existing page like http://beta.fray.it/wp-content/themes/fray/components/invite/twitter/mypage2.php, still I get the same results, what the f***?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you enable WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_LOG in wp-config.php (WP_DEBUG is disabled by default since WP_DEBUG is set to false).

debug.log is generated in your /wp-content/ directory upon an error, warning, a notice or a log call.

You can also utilize a wrapper function to centralize your log calls

```
if(!function_exists('_log')){
  function _log( $message ) {
    if( WP_DEBUG === true ){
      if( is_array( $message ) || is_object( $message ) ){
        error_log( print_r( $message, true ) );
      } else {
        error_log( $message );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

you can read more about that [here](http://fuelyourcoding.com/simple-debugging-with-wordpress/)

Check out the codex as well:
 http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: found out that my problem was due to htaccess. I changed location of my files and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your link `href`

```
 onclick='window.location.href =' + "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>" + '/components/invite/twitter/redirect.php';
```